# Is there in Discrete Fourier Transform a theorem that corresponds to Transforms of Derivatives in the continuous case?

Tags: fourier-analysis

The Fourier Transform of the derivative of a continuous function f has this property:

$$ \mathcal{F}(f')=i \omega \, \mathcal{F}(f)$$

So is there a similar theorem in the field of Discrete Fourier Transform? So far I have not read of a corresponding theorem in the discrete case.

Comment: Now knowing that there is an analogue, I'd like to add a question: Has the subject been explicitly discussed in any book?

Comment: The $DFT$ is a special case of the $Z$ transform. The shifting and finite difference properties are well-known.

Comment: Are you thinking of the [DFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform)  or the [DTFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Fourier_transform)?

Comment: It's the DFT. :)

Comment: @Yves Daoust :Thanks for that comment! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but it's not as cool. Let $f : \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{C}$ be a function. A discrete analogue of the derivative of $f$ is the finite difference $\Delta f(x) = f(x + 1) - f(x)$. Letting $\widehat{f} : \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{C}$ denote the discrete Fourier transform, we have

$$\widehat{f(x + 1)} = \zeta_n^y \widehat{f(x)}$$

where $\zeta_n = e^{ \frac{2 \pi i}{n} }$, and so

$$\widehat{\Delta f} = (\zeta_n^y - 1) \widehat{f}.$$

Comment: To follow up this excellent answer: the finite difference operator plays the role of a derivative in finite calculus, so the analogy is pretty strong.

Comment: Thank you very much for the helpful answer Qiaochu! After pondering for a little while I understand what you said. It is a delightful analogue. There is however one thing which I think is a bit confusing with your answer: the letter x is used again in the frequency domain: that is, the power of zeta.

Comment: @User: yeah, I can fix that if it's confusing.

Comment: What is $y$? IMWTK

Comment: @marty: it's the "frequency" variable.

Answer (score 3):

Let's considering the [DTFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Fourier_transform) (the DFT is similar), with $x[n] \leftrightarrow \mathcal{F}_x(\omega)$.

Let $y[n]=x[n]-x[n-1]$ (a discrete analogous to the derivative). Then

$$\mathcal{F}_y(\omega)=\mathcal{F}_x(\omega)\left (1- e^{-i \omega} \right) $$

To see the connection, take the first order approximation: $e^{-i \omega} \approx 1 - i \omega$

Comment: Thank you. I think that first order approximation is enlightening!

Answer (score 2):

consider the discrete Fourier transform of a signal $x_n$ 
$$X_k = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x_n e^{-2 i \pi nk / N}$$ 
if $N$ is even, you get the trigonometric interpolation of $x_n$ as
$$x(t) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=-N/2}^{N/2-1} X_k e^{2 i \pi k t/ N}$$

so its derivative is

$$x'(t) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=-N/2}^{N/2-1} \frac{2 i \pi k}{N} X_k e^{2 i \pi k t / N}$$ by sampling it you get $y_n = x'(n)$ whose discrete Fourier transform is

$$Y_k = \sum_{n=-N/2}^{N/2-1} y_n e^{-2 i \pi nk / N} = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}\frac{2 i \pi k}{N} X_k&  \text{if } k < N/2 \\ 
\frac{2 i \pi (k-N)}{N} X_k& \text{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.$$

so multiplying a discrete Fourier transform  by $$H_k = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}\frac{2 i \pi k}{N} &  \text{if } k < N/2 \\ 
\frac{2 i \pi (k-N)}{N} & \text{otherwise}\end{array}\right.$$ corresponds to taking the derivative of the trigonometric interpolation : $h_n$ the inverse discrete Fourier transform of $H_k$ is said to be a **discrete derivative filter**.

there are many discrete derivative filters, all with their pros and cons.

- $[1,-1]$ is among them and has the advantage to be the simplest and the most local,
- but $h_n$ has the advantage to be ideal if the signal to be differentiated has been sampled from a continuous (periodic) function respecting the Shannon theorem (only its $N/2$ first Fourier series  coefficients are non-zeros)

Comment: Thank you very much! Although the calculation looks a bit complicated, the idea is very intuitive. It is strange that the result obtained in this way is different from Qiaochu Yuan's. Since I am not familiar with the details trigonometric interpolation, I don't know for sure what has happened.

Comment: @reuns I know this is an old post, but would you mind if I tested this and got back to you in a couple days? I've been trying to work on recovering the Fourier Transform of $x[n]$ using the Fourier Transform of it's derivative for about week now and this looks like what I was looking for.